# Get image url back in fileupload

Tags: vb.net

i have created an item with an image now, i want to update the item and also the image, how can i get back the image path to the file upload please

I tried to look everywhere some tell me, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

```
     picturebox1.Image=Image.FromFile("URL or image")
```

Was that your question I didn't really get it, did you mean that you want to change the image on runtime?

Regards

Comment: NO I WANT TO RETRIEVE THE URL OF AN IMAGE AND PUT IN A FILEUPLOAD

Comment: If you mean to upload to a image upload website, you can't, I tried it before and it didn't work, you need to solve the captcha. If you want to solve captcha by yourself, you can use this code to get captcha to picturebox:PictureBox1.Load(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("captcha Id here"))